# Release built DLL with Debug.WriteLine

Tags: c#

If I build a DLL in release mode and subsequently use it in debug build when linked will the debug statements be missing?

The reason I ask is we have a logger which can optionally write to the output window when in Debug. The DLL this code is located in will end up being built in release mode and used as a dependency elsewhere. While the dependency app is being used in debug I would like the statements to appear. Will they be stripped when I build the DLL?

EDIT: Closing Due To Duplicate, Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code of the `Debug.WriteLine` method, you will see:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteLine(string message, string category)
{
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(message, category);
}
```

So basically, the call to this methods will only be compiled if you have set the `DEBUG` flag. Typically, when using the `Debug` configuration of your project.